# Как правильно создать отдельную модель для pivot таблицы в связи многие ко многим?

Tags: php, laravel

Я пишу небольшой проект, пусть это будет библиотека. Использую пакет для админки от `frozennode/laravel-administrator`.

Имеются следующие таблицы: `books, offices, book_office`. У таблицы `book_office`, помимо полей `book_id, office_id` есть поле `available`, которое означает наличие книги в том или ином офисе. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в используемом для админки пакете не предусмотрен функционал, отвечающий за взаимодействие с такого рода полями. Прочитал, что для этих целей лучше создать доп. модель для связующей таблицы, и отдельным пунктом меню редактировать нужные поля. Вопрос вот в чем, когда я создаю модель и описываю у нее методы, получается вот так:

```
class BookOffice extends \Eloquent
{
    /**
     * Model's table
     * 
     * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'book_office';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class, 'book_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function office()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Office::class, 'office_id');
    }

}
```

Но при обращении к тому или иному методу, получается ошибка, так как по умолчанию у моделей свойство `protected $primaryKey = 'id';`

На данный момент я добавил в таблицу колонку `id`, но боюсь, что это не совсем правильно, так как первичный ключ у меня был установлен на `book_id + office_id`.

Подскажите, есть ли для моей проблемы предусмотренное в `Laravel` решение?

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно создавать модель, можно указать связь многие ко многим:

```
class Book {
    public function office {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Office', 'book_office', 'book_id', 'office_id')
                  ->withPivot('available');
    }
}
```

Аналогично для Office. Подробнее [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) и [тут](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsToMany).

Comment: Именно так и реализовано. Вопрос стоит именно в создании модели для pivot таблицы. Это продиктовано особенностью пакета администратора, т.к. он не умеет работать с доп. полями в отношении многие ко многим.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в laravel не поддерживаются составные ключи https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

Comment: Да, составные ключи не поддерживаются, но я надеялся, что в laravel есть отдельный хак для этого. Ну что ж, получается нужно все таки добавлять id колонку в таблицу связей